# et {${x_{n}}$} be a sequence and $x \in R$ such that there exists a $k \in N$ such that for all $n \ge k$, $x_n = x$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let {${x_{n}}$} be a sequence and $x \in R$ such that there exists a $k \in N$ such that for all $n \ge k$, $x_n = x$. Prove that {${x_n}$} converges to $x$.

I tried to do $\lim x_{n} = x$  and $\mid x_{n} - x\mid    = -x_{n} + x < -x_{k} +x < \epsilon$

But it doesnt make sense... To do what I did, I have to know that $x$ is supremum which is greater than or equal to $x_{n}$

Comment: The first $k$ terms of a sequence (no matter how large $k$ is) do not affect its limit.

Comment: Which way do I have to use to prove this question..?

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that
$$
\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n:n\geq N\implies |x_n-x|<\epsilon
$$

Let $\epsilon>0$. Taking $N:=k$ where $k$ is the number given in the problem statement, we get
$$
\forall n:n\geq N\implies |x_n-x|=0<\epsilon
$$
Done.

Comment: What ... ? that's it..?  so I can just use $\mid x_n - x \mid = 0  $????? wow..

Comment: @Kwangi Yu Well, (eventually) constant sequences are certainly among the nicest ones you can encounter...